# Bitbucket Pipelines: Build iOS for CI CD without external dependency

Tags: ios, build-automation, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

In Android, you can easily build an APK as long as you have Android SDK image. Then create a release (internal, beta, production) automatically on PlayStore. However Apple uses different licensing thus you will need a Mac and XCode in order to build an IPA file. But recently I found out that it seems possible to build one and deploy it to TestFlight using GitHub Action [here](https://engineering.talkdesk.com/test-and-deploy-an-ios-app-with-github-actions-44de9a7dcef6) (Please verify). We want to avoid setting up physical Mac device, runner and third party when building a release. Is this possible now for Bitbucket Pipeline as well? What could be the easiest way to make the setup work just like on Android? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible now for Bitbucket Pipeline as well?

It could be, considering Bitbucket just published (Sept. 2022):

> ### [Announcing macOS Runners in Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/blog/macos-runners-bitbucket)
>
> We are happy to announce that Bitbucket Pipelines now supports macOS self-hosted runners. We have moved from beta to an official release.
>
> You can now create a self-hosted runner and run it on your macOS infrastructure to run macOS and iOS builds. Since you’re using your own runner, you won't be charged for Bitbucket Pipelines build minutes.
>
> This self-hosted runner will be non-containerised allowing your CI/CD step to access the host's hardware, such as the graphics card or any connected external devices.
> Given that the runner will run directly on a macOS instance, we also don't put restrictions on a step's memory usage.
>
> [image: https://rlmr51w5rw3n7zek1m7tizzg-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/mac-runners-bitbucket.png]

That is:

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            runs-on:
              - macos
            script:
              - swift build
              - swift test
        - step:
            name: Code linting
            runs-on:
              - macos
            script:
              - swiftlint
```

See more with this video "[Bitbucket Pipelines Runners - Demo Den - August 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ditUFbBZpts)".

Answer (score 2):

As of right now Bitbucket Pipelines does not have support for cloud hosted iOS builds. See the following link for the limitations of Bitbucket Pipelines.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/limitations-of-bitbucket-pipelines/

> Currently we don't support building Windows, macOS, or iOS applications (watch the linked issues to receive updates).

You can watch the linked Jira issue to receive updates as they work on this feature:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-13719

The only way to build iOS on Bitbucket Pipelines, without relying on other third party tools is by using your own physical Mac hardware, but I know you mentioned that you are trying to avoid that. Just for the sake of completeness, here are the instructions for how to do that in case anyone else finds it helpful:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-runners-for-macos/

Comment: Building `iOS` is only possible on `MacOS`, and `MacOS`-platform's license only allows running on Apple-hardware. It's a huge chain of limitations, made by Apple, which BitBucket aims to workaround soon by clustering Apple-hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible

you can use
"GitlabCi" and "Fastlane"
https://fastlane.tools/

In Github, you can use Build Actions And even Test with Script

these days Apple launches a new approach named is Xcode Cloud, which is a beta version.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode-cloud/beta/

Comment: Thanks but we do not want to rely on other external tools besides Github Actions.

Comment: Then you can't build iOS images in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible Without using external dependency.

After a lot of trial and error, I figured it out by combining all the solutions.

Where you need an app store key to use in the exportOptions.info file.
You can validate and upload it on the App Store.

Don't worry about what is exportOptions file, How to validate and upload.

> I am sharing a document I published on Medium to resolve the issue.
> This includes What type of architecture you should use for different
> situations and for other Branches.

By applying the given information, Upload on Testflight will be fast as well as Your IPA will take less time to ready for the internal or external tester.

> [Flutter — iOS App Release on App Store using CLI.](https://medium.com/@parthg500/flutter-ios-app-release-on-app-store-using-cli-f15ff3910148)
>
> [Flutter — iOS App Release on AppStore using Bitbucket Pipeline.](https://medium.com/@parthg500/flutter-ios-app-release-on-appstore-using-bitbucket-pipeline-255a0b6c0976)

If this solution helps you. Clap on the Medium Post.

Thank You!!